# docker-compose run command: unable to successfully work Windows 10

Tags: docker, powershell, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

When I run the command `docker-compose` up this keeps coming up and is stuck in an infinite loop of it. It starts both services but then it gets stuck at the message about `es-03` which I have no idea why its doing that if I do not have it. Is there something causing this?

Inside of my `docker-compose.yml` file I have the following:

```yaml
version: '2.2'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.12.1
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

  kib01: 
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.12.1
    container_name: kib01
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://es01.9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://es01:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local

networks:
   elastic:
     driver: bridge
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to start a multi-node cluster, where `es01`, `es02` and `es03` are the nodes, but your docker compose only have the configuration for one node, the `es01` node.

These two lines tells your `es01` node to look for the `es02` and `es03` nodes to form a cluster.

```
discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
```

If you just want a single-node cluster, you need to change your environment in your docker compose, try this.

```
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
```

Comment: Oh I see I am sorry I did not realize that I was doing a multi-node cluster. I am new to this, thank you for clarifying this! It worked thank you again!